# Matlab fmincon with zero user-supplied hessian

Tags: optimization, matlab, convex-optimization, constrained-optimization

I have to solve the problem

$$\min_x 1^Tx+\frac{\lambda}{2}\|\Omega\mu-x\|_2^2+\frac{\beta}{2}\|x-\bar{\gamma}\|_2^2\quad\text{w.r.t.}\quad Px-c=0,\ \ x\geq0$$

and in order to do that with Matlab I am currently using `fmincon` like that:

```
FMinValue = @(x) sum(x)            + lambda * sum((Omega*mu - x).^2) / 2 + beta * sum((x - gamma_bar).^2) / 2;
GradFMin  = @(x) ones(length(x),1) + lambda * (Omega*mu - x)             + beta * (x - gamma_bar);
Fmin = @(x) FMin(x, FMinValue, GradFMin); % merges FMinValue and GradFMin so that fmincon can handle it
HessianFPlusLagrangianPart = @(x, lagrange_multiplier) spdiags((beta-lambda)*ones(length(x),1),0,length(x),length(x));

options = optimoptions('fmincon', 'Algorithm', 'interior-point' , 'GradObj', 'on', 'Hessian', 'user-supplied', 'HessFcn', HessianFPlusLagrangianPart);
x = fmincon(Fmin, ones(length(gamma_bar), 1), [], [], P_bar, c_bar, zeros(length(gamma_bar), 1), [], [], options);
```

Here $\lambda$ and $\beta$ are fixed parameters which could be equal. If that is the case then $\lambda-\beta=0$ which means my hessian matrix is zero as well. Of course I get the Matlab warning `Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled`, but a zero hessian is correct in this case.

Any suggestions what to do in this situation? Unfortunately I cannot change to `lsqnonlin` because I have got the linear term `sum(x)` in my objectiv function. And I cannot use another algorithm instead of `interior-point` either, since I have bound and linear constraints at the same time.

How to overcome this problem and make it work for all choices of $\lambda$ and $\beta$?

Comment: At first, I wonder why you want to use the general nonlinear solver to solve a simple convex quadratic problem (for which there are loads of efficient solvers for MATLAB)? Second, the linear term is no problem, $x+(x-\gamma)^2 = (x-(\gamma-1/2))^2-1/4+\gamma$. Generalize and you'll see lsqnonlin is applicable.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that very useful comment! With that reformulation I can even use `lsqlin`. This should actually be the right answer. Regarding your first question: I just wanted to use `fmincon`, because I thought there is no applicable, more specific solver. Of course I wasn't happy with it at all. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is (likely) that your gradient and Hessian are incorrect:
$$\nabla \left(\frac\lambda 2 \|\Omega\mu-x\|_2^2 \right)= \lambda(\Omega\mu-x)(-1) = \lambda(x-\Omega\mu)$$
and hence the corresponding part of the Hessian is
$$\nabla^2 \left(\frac\lambda 2 \|\Omega\mu-x\|_2^2 \right) = \lambda I.$$

Comment: Thanks, yes, you are totally right. I forgot the $-1$ from the inner derivative which would yield $\lambda+\beta$ in the hessian. Still the little problem remains, what to do if $\lambda=-\beta$, but I don't even know if I need this case. I guess not... Thanks again! Thinking to delete the question...

Comment: Penalty parameters should always be nonnegative, so I would be surprised if this case came up in practice.

Answer (score 2):

One way you could overcome this situation is to correct the Hessian of your objective function, which should be $(\lambda + \beta)I$, and then see if you still have scaling issues.